# why is cakephp throwing error?

Tags: validation, cakephp

I'm trying to create a validation in the controller, to check that in the relationship table the username of the person they are sending the bill too and there name is in there with an active field before the site saves the invoice in the database

relationships table is `id, partyone, partytwo, active, expirydate`. The validation is throwing this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

```
 public function add(){

 if($this->request->is('post')){
 $this->Invoice->set($this->request->data);
 if(this->Invoice->validates(array('fieldList'=>array('Relationship.partyone','Relationship.active')){
  $this->Invoice->create(); 
 if ($this->Invoice->saveAll($this->request->data,array('validate'=>false))) 
 { 
  $this->Session->setFlash('The invoice has been saved');  
} else { 
      $this->Session->setFlash('The invoice could not be saved. Please, try again.');
      $errors=$this->Invoice->validationErrors;
    }

  } 

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you forgot the dollar sign before `this`.

```
if(this->Invoice->validates(array('fieldList'=>array('Relationship.partyone','Relationship.active')){
```

should be

```
if($this->Invoice->validates(array('fieldList'=>array('Relationship.partyone','Relationship.active')){
```